# How do I prove monotonicity of risk measures?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, risk-assessment

Assume I have a risk measure, that is a functional $R:L^\infty(\Omega, F,P)\to \mathbb{R}$, that applies to random variables $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.
Assume the functional satisfies the following properties

1. It is *monotonic*: $X\geq 0 \implies R(X)\leq 0$
2. It is *convex*: $R(\lambda X+(1-\lambda)Y)\leq \lambda R(X)+(1-\lambda)R(Y)$ for $\lambda\in[0,1]$.
3. It is *positively homogeneous*: $R(\lambda X)=\lambda R(X)$ for $\lambda\geq 0$.

Given these three properties, I should be able to derive the following. For any two random variables $X$ and $Y$, with $X\geq Y$, then the risk measure satisfied $R(X)\leq R(Y)$. That is, greater values imply smaller risk.

This fact should be a mere consequence of the three properties above. However, I am not able to complete the proof.

**My attempt**

This is how I am starting:
\begin{align*}
R(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y)&=R(\lambda X + Y -\lambda Y)\\
&\leq \lambda R(X)+(1-\lambda)R(Y)\\
&=\lambda R(X)+ R(Y)-\lambda R(Y)
\end{align*}
I was hoping the fact that $X-Y\geq 0$ and $R(X-Y)\leq 0$ could turn out useful, but I cannot see where to use it.

**My question**

Any hint as to how to continue?

Comment: And so ? what have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? Maybe try to work with $Z=X-Y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convexity and positive homogeneity,
$$\begin{align}R(X)&=R\left(\frac{2Y+2(X-Y)}2\right)\\
&\le\frac{R(2Y)+R(2(X-Y))}2\\
&=R(Y)+R(X-Y),
\end{align}$$
hence by monotonicity, if $X-Y\ge0$ then $R(X)\le R(Y).$